# Savon gem shows (unknown keyword: :message)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wsdl, savon

I'm trying to adapt Ryan Bates's railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/290-soap-with-savon?autoplay=true to use Savon to a wsdl, but I'm getting "ArgumentError (unknown keyword: :message)"

Step by step: brazilian mail company

1. wsdl:
   https://apphom.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl
2. test it on SoapUI 5.5.0

New Soap Project

3. Initial wsdl: https://apphom.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl
4. Service: consulta cep
5. after hitting request 1, I get

   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cli="http://cliente.bean.master.sigep.bsb.correios.com.br/">
   soapenv:Header/
   soapenv:Body
   cli:consultaCEP

   ?
   </cli:consultaCEP>
   </soapenv:Body>
   </soapenv:Envelope>
6. "cep" means "zip code", and Replacing "?" for "81531980" (a valid zip code), and submitting request I get the following:

   <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   soap:Body
   <ns2:consultaCEPResponse xmlns:ns2="http://cliente.bean.master.sigep.bsb.correios.com.br/">

   Jardim das Américas
   81531980
   Curitiba

   Avenida Coronel Francisco Heráclito dos Santos 100
   PR

   </ns2:consultaCEPResponse>
   </soap:Body>
   </soap:Envelope>

The next step is to do the same with savon. So, I created a new rails app, bundle savon gem and enter console:

```
> rails c
2.7.0 :001 > client = Savon.client(wsdl: "https://apphom.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl")
2.7.0 :002 > client.operations
... :consulta_cep ...
2.7.0 :003 > response = client.call(:consulta_cep, message: { cep: '81531980'} )
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):10
Savon::SOAPFault ((soap:Server) The given SOAPAction consultaCEP does not match an operation.)
2.7.0 :004 > response = client.call(:cli, :consulta_cep, message: { cep: '81531980'} )
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):10
        1: from (irb):11:in `rescue in irb_binding'
ArgumentError (unknown keyword: :message)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the `SOAPAction` HTTP header. To do so, add `soap_action: false`.

```
client = Savon.client(
  wsdl: "https://apphom.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl"
)

response = client.call(:consulta_cep, soap_action: false, message: { cep: '81531980' })

response.body[:consulta_cep_response][:return][:bairro] #=> "Jardim das Américas"
```